# Connecting to VPN server in Android

Tags: android, vpn

I have been working on developing an android client for connecting to a VPN server. I have these concepts for now

- Android version 14+ provide an API named VpnService.
- You have to implement your own protocols even common protocols like 
  PPTP,L2TP, IKEV2 etc.

Now I am supposed to connect VPN service via ikev2 protocol. Where i can find the

- Manual implementation of ikev2 protocol.
- How can I integrate it in android studio.

I have gone through many 
   blogs and github codes but none of them seems to solve my issue. Thanx!

Comment: This question might be off-topic (see point 4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Did you look at [strongSwan's Android app](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AndroidVPNClient)? [Build instructions](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AndroidVPNClientBuild) can be found on the wiki. The code is licensed under the GPLv2 (but a commercial license is available).

Comment: Strongswan does not support IKEV2 using pre shared key.

Comment: It does, the app just doesn't expose this functionality because it's potentially very insecure (using at least a certificate on the server-side prevents rogue servers from capturing hashes of possibly weak user passwords).